# Mouseenter event is fired twice even when mouse has moved out

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I am adding two shake animation to a div when the page loads and when  mouseenter event happen on the div

I have the shame animation called with different names shake1 and shake2 that I want to play when the page load and again when the div is hovered. Below is how the html, css and js look

```js
let $image = document.querySelector("div");
$image.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  $image.style.animationPlayState = "running";
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  animation-name: shake1;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes shake1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: shake2;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes shake2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height: 100px;">
</div>
```

I expect the shake animation to work when the page loads and again work when the div is hovered. But it is playing when page loads and also play when mouseenter event happen on the div and it also play when mouse leave the div. I think the on load animation is playing when the mouse leave the div as if the page has loaded. How do I get this to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is caused by the fact that you have defined two different animations on your target element, so when you set animationPlayState to 'running' it fires the two.

I have updated your code to log the current animation name:

```js
let $image = document.querySelector(".shake");

$image.addEventListener("animationstart", function(event) {
  console.log(event.animationName);
})

$image.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
  $image.style.animationPlayState = "running";
});
```

```css
div.shake {
  background: red;
  animation-name: shake1;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes shake1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}

div.shake:hover {
  animation-name: shake2;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes shake2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shake" style="width:100px; height: 100px;">
</div>
```

As a workaround you could set the animationPlayState to "paused" on mouseleave:

```js
let $image = document.querySelector("div");
$image.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  $image.style.animationPlayState = "running";
});

$image.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  $image.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  animation-name: shake1;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes shake1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: shake2;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes shake2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height: 100px;">
</div>
```